# Does/can Windows 10 keep track of file moves/copies/shortcut creations?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, logging, events

Numerous times a day, I get the feeling that I accidentally created a shortcut in File Explorer, or that I accidentally copied or moved a dir/file.

I keep looking for the "History box", but then remember that Windows 10 is not Adobe Photoshop. Is there some kind of built-in feature which would allow me to nicely see the last few "events" of this specific kind? So that I can verify that I didn't make any bad accidental file operation?

(Please don't tell me "Event Viewer", because I've not once in my life been able to extract any useful information from that thing!)

If Windows does keep track of this in a way which allows me to extract the data for further processing by my own scripts, that would also be nice to hear. Like, maybe they allow me to do something like:

```
eventviewer.exe --extract-latest-file-operation-events --format=JSON --output="C:\test\log.json" --limit=100
```

That would be great.

Comment: This is available for changes to the file system using Auditing, but it isn't a friendly list of changes presented easily. Auditing is designed for multi-user enterprise systems.

Answer (score 1):

This is called Auditing, but is designed for business systems and presents a log of changes made to a filesystem in a technical format, not an easy to read list: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder

> You can apply audit policies to individual files and folders on your computer by setting the permission type to record successful access attempts or failed access attempts in the security log.
>
> To complete this procedure, you must be signed in as a member of the built-in Administrators group or have Manage auditing and security log rights.
>
> To apply or modify auditing policy settings for a local file or folder Select and hold (or right-click) the file or folder that you want to audit, select Properties, and then select the Security tab.
>
> Select Advanced.
>
> In the Advanced Security Settings dialog box, select the Auditing tab, and then select Continue.
>
> Do one of the following:
>
> To set up auditing for a new user or group, select Add. Select Select a principal, type the name of the user or group that you want, and then select OK.
>
> To remove auditing for an existing group or user, select the group or user name, select Remove, select OK, and then skip the rest of this procedure. To view or change auditing for an existing group or user, select its name, and then select Edit. In the Type box, indicate what actions you want to audit by selecting the appropriate check boxes:
>
> To audit successful events, select Success.
>
> To audit failure events, select Fail.
>
> To audit all events, select All. In the Applies to box, select the object(s) to which the audit of events will apply. These include:
>
> This folder only This folder, subfolders and files This folder and
> subfolders This folder and files Subfolders and files only Subfolders
> only Files only By default, the selected Basic Permissions to audit
> are the following:
>
> Read and execute List folder contents Read Additionally, with your
> selected audit combination, you can select any combination of the
> following permissions: Full control Modify Write

*apologies for formatting. I'm pasting on mobile. I'll try to get this cleaned up later. *